# How to make sure that a given filename is safe (doesn't exist) to write to?

Tags: php, linux

I have this code (detail of bigger function):

```
$candidate_file_path = '/tmp/data/dir/test_123.txt'; // In the real code, it just keeps trying _1, _2, _3, etc. filenames until one of them doesn't exist.

clearstatcache();
if (!file_exists($candidate_file_path))
{
    if (fopen($candidate_file_path, 'x'))
    {
        clearstatcache();
        return $candidate_file_path;
    }
}
```

It keeps logging the error `fopen(/tmp/data/dir/test_123.txt): Failed to open stream: File exists`. So there is some sort of frustrating race condition going on. But the whole point of doing the `file_exists` call right before is to make sure that it doesn't exist, and we use the `x` option with `fopen`.

I've had problems with this function for ages and it never seems to work right, no matter how many times I recode it and try to figure out what exactly needs to be done. What do I need to do to make it "reserve" the file so that no other scripts can possibly try to use the same filename?

For the time being, I have started adding the current time in microseconds to the filename, to further make it less likely that two different scripts try to use the same filename at the same time, but this feels like a very ugly and unreliable hack and it makes the function not work the way it's supposed to: it's supposed to guarantee a unique filename in any dir based on the desired one.

**Before you tell me about `flock()`, I know of this! And its manual examples make zero sense, since fopen is executed before the `flock()` call, which means it will log/print the error no matter what when it already exists.**

Comment: did using `tempnam()`approach also not work?

Comment: @Adi I had no idea that function existed in PHP... What does it do internally?

Comment: It combines the specified directory path with a unique identifier to create a new temporary file basically generates a unique temporary filename

Comment: @Adi I mean, what does it do differently from what my code is doing?

Comment: Your way you are creating a unique filename by appending _1, _2, and so on, in case the file already existed. Where as `tempnam()` generates a unique filename in a more atomic way combining the directory path and a unique identifier to create a filename that is not only unique at the moment of creation but is also less susceptible to race conditions

Comment: So adding timestamps in microseconds also work but its effectiveness depends on the precision of the timestamp and the likelihood of collisions in a high-concurrency environment, possibility of two processes generating the same timestamp.

Comment: Out of curiosity have you check the Linux file path permissions. Maybe php is not able to read the file path. Hence it passes the check. hence it creates a file. however there is a file already there.